# Ideas to tackle unwanted bad press/review on Google's SERP?

Tags: seo, google

After Googling our company name to our horror we've found someone on Yelp.co.uk has reviewed our company. On the SERP your eye is immediately drawn to the 2 star review some complete stranger has written, which to be honest is pure slander! The most infuriating thing is the person who reviewed our company has never even been a client/customer.

It's a bit like me reviewing a restaurant having never eaten or even been in there!

We've sent her a private message on Yelp to remove the review and also sent a complaint to Yelp themselves but have yet to get a reply. We've resisted going mad at the reviewer and also requested that she re-review us having just relaunched our new website (it still riles us that she's not even a client though!).

We've had genuine customers/clients review us on Yelp yet this 2 star review remains on Google's SERP. Roughly how long would it take to for our new reviews to over take this review?

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how we can push the review off the 1st page of Google's SERP or any creative ways in which we can tackle this issue?

Comment: Judging by the votes it seems like a few other would like to know this aswell!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yelp came back to us and removed the bad review as it "breached the content guidelines". I can't help but think it was the stern words I used in the request!

Anyways, the moral of the story I guess is to contact the site the bad review/press is on and get them to directly remove the article in question.

The second moral is Google your own company name to stop any bad press as quickly as possible... especially if it's pure slander like this was.